# Access private struct within class c++

Tags: c++

Trying to implement an adjacency matrix graph and practice OOP. I've been stuck on implementing the inserNode(string ) method.

My troubles are with accessing the private data fields. What am I completely missing?

Some of the errors:

Graph.cpp:30:26: error: unknown type name 'node'
             graph[id] = new node;
                             ^

Graph.cpp:35:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'numnodes'
             numnodes++;

Graph.cpp:34:19: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
         graph[id]->nodename = name;

Graph.cpp:34:15: error: decomposition declaration '[id]' requires an initializer

graph.h

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Graph {

    public:
        Graph();
        int insertNode(string name);

    private:
        static const int vertices = 20;
        int nodeCount;

        struct node {
            int nodeid; // node position in graph[]
            string nodename; // username
        };

        // pointers to the graph nodes 
        node *graph[vertices];

        // adjacency matrix for graph. True if edge is going from node i to j.
        bool edges[vertices][vertices];
};

#endif
```

graph.cpp

```
#include "Graph.h"

Graph::Graph() {
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices; i++) {
        graph[i] = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < vertices; j++ )
            edges[i][j] = 0;
    }
}

      /* create node and insert pointer in first  available graph position. Returns id value, -1 if unsuccessful. */
int insertNode(string name) {
    int id = 0;
    while (id < vertices) {
        if (graph[id] == NULL) {
            graph[id] = new node;
                if (!graph[id]) 
                    return -1;
                 graph[id]->nodeid = id;
                 graph[id]->nodename = name;
                 numnodes++;
                 return id;
        }
        id++;
   }
   return -1;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `using namespace std;`. Especially not in header files.

Comment: Use `node *graph[vertices]{};` and `bool edges[vertices][vertices]{};` (mind the curly brackets) instead of the for-loops in the constructor. Then you can `Graph() = default;` your constructor and remove the definition of it from graph.cpp.

Answer (score 1):

The `insertNode` you've defined is not the same way you declared in `Graph`. You've just made a free function called `insertNode`, which isn't a member of `Graph` and therefore can't access `Graph`. You need to define it like so:

```
int Graph::insertNode(string name)
{
}
```